# How achieve rounded shadow behide a rounded element using css3

Tags: html, css

i want to make a element look like in this image

[image: Round shadow on element]

i have tried a a lot to do this kind of shadow in css, and finally think why not ask to community about it, whether its possible or not.

i know in `box-shadow` means shadow on box. is there something like `round-shodow`

i want it in css3 without any images.
is it possible? if yes then how is it possible? if no than ok.

i know `box-shadow` and `border-radius` very so please don't tell me about that things, check again its different kind of shadow

Comment: Won't a box shadow do this if you stick it on an element that also has `border-radius: 50%`?

Comment: Just play with border-radius, as another comment stated it.

Comment: i know that well, but what about shadow, i don't mean that i want to use box-shadow

Comment: @Sheikh  border-radius and box-shadow don't so that trick

Comment: @MeghrajChoudhary plz use Edit if you want to add something to a comment you've only written a couple of seconds ago.

Comment: [Is this ok](http://jsfiddle.net/mZRBv/3/) ?

Comment: nope, see 3 voted Torr3nt 's answer

Comment: @MeghrajChoudhary, It's now 4 voted, including mine too and you got one too :-)

Comment: yes, its worth, its will be my accepted answer, if someone else know  another approce then i am waiting for little while

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a starting point at least. You can use the before (and after) pseudo elements. http://jsfiddle.net/FHLJM/

```
div {
    background-color: #f00;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
div:before {
    content: '';
    height: 150px;
    width: 250px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#000), to(#fff));;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    right: 50px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    z-index: -1;
}
div:after {
    content: '';
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #f00;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Again, it's not a perfected method by any means, but it is able to accomplish what you're looking for to some degree.

Comment: i understand, its not perfect but at least i can do little more trick to get what i want

Comment: That'll only work on webkit browsers. For cross-browser compatibility, you'll need the other browser-specific gradient and transform properties.

Comment: Right... it's just a start. I was under the impression I'm not teaching him code, he just needed a little jump start.

Comment: yes, we all know code very well, but need to know where and which way we do jumb

Answer (score 1):

If want an easy way to do this with JS i have had really good luck with this

https://github.com/heyimjuani/iluminate

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's some css that gives you about the effect you're asking for:

```
.circle { background: red; border-radius: 50%; width: 50px; height:50px;position:relative;}
.circle:before {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(136,136,136,0.4) 0%, rgba(136,136,136,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(136,136,136,0.4)), color-stop(100%,rgba(136,136,136,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(136,136,136,0.4) 0%,rgba(136,136,136,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(136,136,136,0.4) 0%,rgba(136,136,136,0) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(136,136,136,0.4) 0%,rgba(136,136,136,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(136,136,136,0.4) 0%,rgba(136,136,136,0) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#66888888', endColorstr='#00888888',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    width:100%;
    height:75%;
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    position: relative;
    top: 22px;
    right: 15px;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform:rotate(45deg);
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RKwdj/

Comment: Not even close on chrome 29.0.1547.66

Comment: The fiddle lacks the -webkit and -ms-transform properties - I forgot to add them, then edited them into my answer. Is that the problem you're seeing?